# ModuleNotFoundError after build exe by pyinstaller

Tags: pyinstaller

My project folder as below:

```
C:\HHS\Actions<mysomeclass>.py

C:\HHS\Configuration<mysomesetting>.txt

C:\HHS\Data<mysomedata>.txt

C:\HHS\Form<mysomeclass>.py

C:\HHS\Testcases<mysometestcaseclass>.py

C:\HHS\Labels\OCR\Tmp<somefile>.png

C:\HHS\main.py

C:\HHS<somebatfile>.bat
```

After build exe file by command: C:\HHS>pyinstaller --paths=C:\HHS\Actions;C:\HHS\Form;C:\HHS\Testcase main.py

I copy all folder Actions , Configuration, Data, Form , Testcase, all file .bat to C:\HHS\dist\main

After that I run file main.exe in dist\main. It overcome the previous issue ([How to release an application write by Python (which has structure folder) to user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72123397/how-to-release-an-application-write-by-python-which-has-structure-folder-to-us))  but I met the other issue as below:

```
C:\HHS\dist\main>main.exe
Which testcase do you want to test
1. Image Capture
2. Reset Base
3. OCRTestcase
4. USBOEMCommand (remember turn off Vietnamese)
Please enter that number : 1 

C:\HHS\dist\main> py C:\HHS\dist\main\Testcases\ImageCapture.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:\HHS\dist\main\Testcases\ImageCapture.py", line 9, in <module>
     from Actions.Config import Config
ModuleNotFoundError: No module name 'Actions'
```

This is my ImageCapture.py

```
import os
import serial
import time
import sys
import os
import logging
from Actions.Config import Config
import Actions.Common as Common
from datetime import datetime
from Actions import DBv2
from Actions.parselog2 import ParseLog
```

I know maybe how I import module Actions is not correct (although it can run successful by Pycharm) but not work after build exe. I don't know how to fix it. Please help me. Thanks alot.

Comment: Can you run the generation of the exe by openning a cmd in the location of the script and run `pyinstaller main.py`. After this, go to `dist` folder -> `your project name folder -> run `main.exe` without cpying anything and without mentioning any path when using `pyinstaller`

Comment: I follow as your suggest and it still has the error ModuleNotFoundError like as question above (although I also copy folder Testcases (contain file ImageCaputre.py).

Comment: That's already strange. Can you open a `cmd` in `C:\HHS` and try `python main.py`? I am trying to eliminate all posibilities for an error before looking for a solution about used tools

Comment: It met the same error. I also think it does not about tool it just about how to import Actions before use tool